# How to Prevent Facebook JavaScript SDK from Loading Mixed Content

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, mixed-content

I have created a web app that allows users to login with Facebook. The content is hosted on an Amazon Web Services server. However, when I run my app, I get the error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/0F7S7QWJ0Ac.js?version=4…6cf&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-34-20[...]' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/rosarivo/v1/OGdIq-p0tOtBN2VMVvO9W_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I am getting a mixed content error because I request http and https resources from the same page. I would just change my page to request only secure resources, but unfortunately, since the HTTP file is being loaded by Facebook, I cannot simply replace http:// with //. My html code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){

      FB.init({
        appId: '767877510042378',
        version: 'v2.9'
      });
      // console.log(FB._https);
      $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am interested if there is some way to force Facebook to load only secure resources.

Comment: The error seems to be about a Google Webfont, and those are not embedded by Facebook, that must be your app’s own doing. (And Facebook itself is not loading anything here, of course - the client’s browser is.)

Comment: That originally seemed likely to me as well. However, I checked the resource request header, which said that the request origin was https://staticxx.facebook.com. So I think that a Facebook script might be requesting the webfont.

Comment: Ha, interesting. That script requesting the web font is a cross-domain helper script, which displays a warning in HTML somehow when called directly in the browser. (Not sure if that is what triggers it to request the web font?) If this stops your app from working, file a bug report with Facebook and ask them to fix it - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/